# What is this Down Arrow from the Menu Bar?

Tags: desktop, menu-bar

[image]

What is this down arrow from the Menu Bar? Can't remove or click on it. Could this be some virus???

Comment: Is it still there after you log out or restart?

Comment: @agarza It disappears after I log out but I'm worried if it's from some virus installed on my laptop.

Comment: A virus is unlikely to advertise its presence by creating a strange arrow. You could always use somethling like MalwareBytes to check for malware; or something like EtreCheck, which will provide you with a report of software that is running in the background.

Comment: @diyun It almost seems as if you were resizing a tab and the computer bugged out and kept the arrow icon on the screen. It's happened to me a few times before but disappeared after I resized another tab.